# How can I run all JUnit tests in one package @ NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I have like trillion test packages with bazillion tests and I want to run just some of packages. Now I must run whole project (some tests takes long to complete) or I need to run every single file manually. How is possible to run just some packages in NetBeans ? I can't find this option ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not what you want, but the NetBeans help topic, *Running a JUnit Test*, says:

> If you want to run a subset of the
>   project's tests or run the tests in a
>   specific order, you can create test
>   suites that specify the tests to run
>   as part of that suite. After creating
>   a test suite you run the suite in the
>   same way you run a single test class.

Creating a test suite is covered in the topic *Creating a JUnit Test*.

Comment: yep I knew that only solution so far is writing suite, but I am actually pretty surprised (or I don't understand how is that not possible) that such an great IDE doesn't offer this feature :/

Comment: @Xorty: Yes, although you can run individual tests in NetBeans, I don't see any other way to run a subset. It is a little easier to run selected tests in Eclipse.

Comment: I use tons of Maven and I am not giving up NetBeans there ... (nothing again Eclipse it's brilliant)

Answer (score 1):

If you use JUnit 4 then try [ClasspathSuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) and its [regex filters](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp#howto).