# Run JUnit Test suite from command line

Tags: java, command-line, junit, junit4, categories

How do I run a Junit 4.8.1 Test suite from command line ?
Also I want to use the categories introduces with JUnit 4.8 , is there a way where
I can specify from command line the category which I want to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way (as of 4.8) to specify categories from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Using `java` run [JUnitCore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html) class (also see [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_4)).

Categories are supposed to be used with test suites with `@RunWith(Categories.class)`
, `@IncludeCategory` and `@ExcludeCategory`. I am not aware of any dynamic way to use categories to run tests but I'd like to know of such it it exists. You can have pre-defined test suites for certain categories to run them.

Comment: It's possible to create custom test runner that dynamically selects tests to run based on categories.

Comment: Here's one way to easily run all tests in a suite/category (without explicitly enumerating the tests): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176570/how-to-run-all-tests-belonging-to-a-certain-category-in-junit-4/2176791#2176791 (Let me know if this is not what you meant.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324623/how-can-i-run-all-junit-tests-in-one-package-netbeans/3332970#3332970). I think what author means is running tests based on category as a parameter.

Comment: The obvious reason to do this is to exclude slow tests (i.e. touches, network, database or disk) from our 10 minute CI build. This gives organizations that have been misusing JUnit a way to filter out that misuse.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two approaches:
1. Create Ant file with junit target and then invoke this target from commend line.
2. Implement test suite class, in it in some class with main() method. So you will be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.10, we do this:

```
mvn verify -p(your profiles) -Dit.test=(SuiteClass)
```

where `SuiteClass` is an empty class (no methods or fields) that is annotated with `@RunWith(Categories.class)` and `@Suite.SuiteClasses({FooIT.class, BarIT.class, ...})`.  `FooIT` and `BarIT` are the integration tests.