# How to execute Junit Test case from command line

Tags: java, command-line, junit

I know this is very common problem and i already did search but somehow it could not resolve my problem.

Here is the problem context:

Created a maven project(Using eclipse with maven quickstart and used Junit version 4.12) for my Junit test cases. Following is the structure-
[image]

And this is the content of Junit file-

```
package JunitRnD.JunitArtifact;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Stack;

import org.junit.Test;

public class AppTest {

    @Test
    public void emptyTest() {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        assertTrue(stack.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Project is located under this location:

```
/Users/_eclipseWork/JunitArtifact
```

And this is the content of the directory-
[image]

Junit test works from eclipse. But i want to run it from command line.
So I used following command-

```
cd /Users/_eclipseWork/JunitArtifact

java -cp .:/Users/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/Users/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore JunitRnD/JunitArtifact/AppTest
```

I also used other variant per directory structure, but always received following error-

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JunitRnD/JunitArtifact/AppTest
```

What am i missing here?

*PS: Also tried with putting .java and .class extension.*

Comment: maven has a "command" to run single tests, FWIW http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: I am working on a use case where need to run test case by a process without Maven

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3997971/2464657

Comment: @Adam Rosini Thanks for the link. But i already tried and it went in vain. Can you please see my directory structure and let me know from where should i run the command?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run Maven to run your test.

```
mvn -Dtest=JunitRnD.JunitArtifact.AppTest test
```

Or, iF you want to run without Maven you need a Test Runner.

Take a look at:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-runners

You can do:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass1 [...other test classes...]
```

Comment: I like the idea of mvn with -Dtest (+1). Thank you for sharing this. But it still does not solve my problem. As i want to run the test cases from command line and also aware of Junitcore and applied the same but its failing as mentioned in my question.